# Opensearch / Elasticsearch tokenizer to split on trailing state abbreviation (regex)

Tags: regex, elasticsearch, tokenize, opensearch

I want Opensearch to tokenize transaction information from my bank for a personal project, but I'm unable to determine the right syntax.

Here are some examples of transaction descriptions:

`amazon web services    aws.amazon.coQA`

`TST* PLUS MEMBERSHIP THRITX`

`UBER EATS    HELP.UBER.COMCA`

`HUMBEBUNDLE.COM   HTTPSWWW.HUMBCA`

`APPLE.COM/BILL    866-712-7753 CA`

The first tokenizing rule I'm trying to establish is to split the trailing 2 letters when they are capitalized state abbreviations:

```
GET /_analyze
{
    "tokenizer": {
        "type": "pattern",
        "pattern": "(?:[ A-Z]|^)(AL|AK|AZ|AR|CA|CO|CT|DE|FL|GA|HI|ID|IL|IN|IA|KS|KY|LA|ME|MD|MA|MI|MN|MS|MO|MT|NE|NV|NH|NJ|NM|NY|NC|ND|OH|OK|OR|PA|RI|SC|SD|TN|TX|UT|VT|VA|WA|WV|WI|WY)$"
      },
  "text": "TST* PLUS MEMBERSHIP HTTPSWWW.THRITX"
}
```

However, this just seems to remove it, not split on it.

```
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "TST* PLUS MEMBERSHIP HTTPSWWW.THR",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 33,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

What is the right way to tell Opensearch to treat the last 2 letters as their own token when they are state abbreviations?

Comment: Maybe `"pattern": "(?=(AL|AK|AZ|AR|CA|CO|CT|DE|FL|GA|HI|ID|IL|IN|IA|KS|KY|LA|ME|MD|MA|MI|MN|MS|MO|MT|NE|NV|NH|NJ|NM|NY|NC|ND|OH|OK|OR|PA|RI|SC|SD|TN|TX|UT|VT|VA|WA|WV|WI|WY)$)"`?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to split the token into two then try the following query

```
GET /_analyze
{
    "tokenizer": "keyword",
    "filter": [
        {
            "type": "pattern_capture",
            "preserve_original": false,
            "patterns": [
                "^(.*)(AL|AK|AZ|AR|CA|CO|CT|DE|FL|GA|HI|ID|IL|IN|IA|KS|KY| LA|ME|MD|MA|MI|MN|MS|MO|MT|NE|NV|NH|NJ|NM|NY|NC| ND|OH|OK|OR|PA|RI|SC|SD|TN|TX|UT|VT|VA|WA|WV|WI|WY)$"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "text": "TST* PLUS MEMBERSHIP THRITX"
}
```

You can't split a token with the pattern tokenizer. We use the noop keyword tokenizer

Answer (score 0):

After reading some documentation of the regex syntax within lucene, this appeared to do the trick:

```
"(\\.*?)(?=[AL|AK|AZ|AR|CA|CO|CT|DE|FL|GA|HI|ID|IL|IN|IA|KS|KY|LA|ME|MD|MA|MI|MN|MS|MO|MT|NE|NV|NH|NJ|NM|NY|NC|ND|OH|OK|OR|PA|RI|SC|SD|TN|TX|UT|VT|VA|WA|WV|WI|WY]{2}\\z)|\\W"
```

The issue I was having was I wasn't properly escaping the leading '.'.

Regardless, opensearch is too expensive of an option for this hobby project so I'll probably have to do this in lambdas.